# Sending multiple whitespace / blankspace with Selenium Webdriver appears impossible

Tags: selenium-webdriver, whitespace, sendkeys

Could you please tell me how to send multiple whitespace / blank space using sendkeys or something similar. I am trying to test acceptance of creating username using multiple withespaces between other characters (like say "user    name"). I was not successfull using a string, using sendkeys "user   name" or using sendkeys(Keys.SPACE) multiple times. It always reduces to one single whitespace. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does my answer solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try sending it with `sendKeys()` method using Actions.

```
public void sendTextAction(By locator, String text){
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    clickVisible(locator);
    action.sendKeys(text).build().perform();
}
```

In case this still will not work try involving this method several times i.e. to send "user    name" try this:

```
sendTextAction(elementLocator,"user");
sendTextAction(elementLocator," ");
sendTextAction(elementLocator," ");
sendTextAction(elementLocator," ");
sendTextAction(elementLocator,"name");
```

but first try this

```
sendTextAction(elementLocator,"user   name");
```